# ALIGN_CENTER cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-poi

Where am i wrong ?

I'm following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvrnbhGeSKE

However, eclipse gives me this error when I paste over the code: "ALIGN_CENTER cannot be resolved or is not a field"

```
package main;

import entities.*;
import dao.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            ProductModel pmodel = new ProductModel();
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("List Products");

            Row rowheading = sheet.createRow(0);
            rowheading.createCell(0).setCellValue("Id");
            rowheading.createCell(1).setCellValue("Name");
            rowheading.createCell(2).setCellValue("Creation Date");
            rowheading.createCell(3).setCellValue("Price");
            rowheading.createCell(4).setCellValue("Quantity");
            rowheading.createCell(5).setCellValue("Sub Total");
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                CellStyle stylerowHeading = workbook.createCellStyle();
                Font font = workbook.createFont();
                font.setBold(true);
                font.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
                font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
                stylerowHeading.setFont(font);
                stylerowHeading.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
                rowheading.getCell(i).setCellStyle(stylerowHeading);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This happens in MainActivity in this snippet of code :

```
stylerowHeading.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    rowheading.getCell(i).setCellStyle(stylerowHeading);
```

The specific error is in the "CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These constants have been moved to a separate class. The proper way should be:

```
stylerowHeading.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
```